# One of two "slave" routers always disconnects after some time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a network setup that can be seen on the picture. The red arrow shows the problematic part. I have 3 netis routers, the main router is connected to the internet, other 2 routers are in a router mode (I tried bridge, no luck) and one of them (router 2) always disconnects after some time.

Each router broadcasts ssid so wifi is enabled on each one of them, all of them have their own subnets, all of them are on different channels, I really don't know what to do.

This is the config of problematic router (it is the same as router 1 which works fine actually)

#### Problematic router

[image: Problematic router]

#### Setup of network

[image: Setup of network]

Comment: Have you bind the IP addresses of the slave routers? (in your picture it say `192.168.0.6`). The slaves are broadcasting the same SSID? (you don't want the router 2 to connect on the router 1).

Comment: Why are you using identical networks (192.168.0.x) on multiple routers? (Not a large problem as long as they have different SSIDs, but they still should be different.)

Comment: I didn't had to mention anything,  I am not the OP :P

Comment: @martin, you didn't mention the channels these routers are configured to. They should be 1,6 and 11 respectively, if any are on the same channel you will get terrible network performance. You mention bridging didn't work, but your IP addressing scheme seems to indicate otherwise. Please update your diagram with this information

Comment: Routers have different channels (1,6, 11) as you mentioned, they also have different SSIDs. And the router 2 cannot connect to router 1 since router 2 does not have router 1's password

Comment: About binding the addresses- they are not bound, they are assigned through DHCP - could this be the problem?

Comment: Do the client routers give you any rssi decibel levels or a percentage indication for signal strength back to the main AP? Ideally rssi and noise levels if it gives them to you would help.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yes, when connecting to the main router, it shows signal strength is at 100%, even though it connects through a good 30centimetres of concrete between two floors, so I assume the signal strength should not be problem. I was thinking, maybe some "connection token" expires or smth. like that.

Comment: This makes me suspicious of that router. in every single environment I have ever installed a wireless AP there has been some background noise. How far away are these two routers? Do router 1 & router 2 have identical firmware versions? It's very abnormal to have 100% signal unless the two devices are directly next to each other.

Comment: yes, I bought all three of them at the same time from same shop. They are not far away, 3 metres at most vertically, its just the houses walls are really thick. Thing is, it works for a week straight and then suddenly boom, router 2 does not have internet connection. It shows it is connected but has ip address set to 0.0.0.0 which is quite a BS, I have to disconnect, restart and sometimes even reset the settings and start all over. I even contaced my ISP he said I should probably return the router and ask for a new one, it may be HW problem